# handling multiple ajax calls in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, axios

I've got the following code in my react component.

```
componentDidMount() {
    getOrganizationsForUserTemp().then((organizations) => {
        this.setState({
            userOrganizations: organizations,
        });
    });

    getUsersOfOrganizationTemp().then((users) => {
        this.setState({
            userOrganizations: users,
        });
    })
}
```

The above code initiates two ajax calls and when the response is retrieved, it updates the state of the component which results in a re-render of the component.

My problem is that, when the first response is received, the component renders perfectly and then when the second response comes, the previously rendered components disappear from the DOM. I guess that when the second response updates the state, there is no reference for the previous response state.

How can I manage multiple ajax calls in such a way that I could have multiple in a single component? what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Since you are storing the response of both ajax calls into the same `state` variable you are facing this issue.

Comment: In the first call you are updating `userOrganizations: organizations` and in the second call you are updating `userOrganizations` with `user`? This does not make sense to me. You should probably have another state variable to hold `users` data and use it to render the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are storing the response of both ajax calls into the same `state` variable you are facing this issue.

You need to do something like

```
componentDidMount() {
    getOrganizationsForUserTemp().then((organizations) => {
        this.setState({
            userOrganizations: organizations,
        });
    });

    getUsersOfOrganizationTemp().then((users) => {
        this.setState({
            users: users,
        });
    })
}
```

`organizations` & `user` are stored in separate state variables.